# Maven - 2.2.1 -------Access denied error

Tags: maven, jenkins

Access denied error coming while building using the maven 2.2.1 build tool

Comment: One of your plugin not able to wright to the folder specified or the file is alredy exist and it is used by another process.

Comment: Often occurs under windows with virus scanners etc. or Usuing an IDE or may be you have opened the file with an editor etc.?

Answer (score 0):

It might be about folder that contains your source code permissions or maven repo authentication. 
First look at the folder permissions. If this does not solve your problem you can try to add `auth` information of the repo that you try to download from,  into your settings file;(Settings file is `settings.xml` in conf folder in your maven installation folder or under .m2 file)

```
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>myrepo</id>
            <username>myusername</username>
            <password>password</password>
        </server>
   </servers>
</settings>
```

You can see this part in your default maven settings file as commented. You can read comments as a simple documentation of settings file.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when multiple processes are trying to access the same file simultaneously.

Most likely one process in reading this file and another is trying to write it at the same time when your IDE where its trying to compile the project while you are running maven from the command line.